# Updating supabase profiles table with users steamid using passport steam

Tags: javascript, next.js, passport.js, supabase

I am trying to update the supabase profiles table with the users steamid. My logic is to somehow access the supabase user object in the passport steam strategy and then update the table using supabase javascript client library to. But the implementations i have tried return `undefined` or some kind of error.

My current strategy looks like this:

```
passport.use(
  new SteamStrategy(
    {
      returnURL: `${process.env.DOMAIN}/api/auth/return`,
      realm: `${process.env.DOMAIN}`,
      apiKey: `${process.env.STEAM_API_KEY}`,
      passReqToCallback: true, // <-- pass the request object to the callback
      passResToCallback: true, // <-- pass the response object to the callback
      passReqRes: true, // <-- pass the request and response objects to the callback
    },
     async (
      req: NextApiRequest,
      res: NextApiResponse,
      _: string,
      profile: SteamProfile,
      done: (a: null | string, b: SteamProfile) => typeof done,

    ) => {
      const supabaseServerClient = createServerSupabaseClient<Database>({
        req,
        res,
      });
      const {
        data: { user },
      } = await supabaseServerClient.auth.getUser();
      console.log(user?.id)
      console.log(profile.id)

      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);`
```

Which does indeed return the users supabase id in the console.log. But now profile.id is undefined and i get 2 errors:

```
TypeError: context.res.getHeader is not a function
    at setCookie (/var/task/node_modules/.pnpm/@supabase+auth-helpers-nextjs@0.6.0_7jdpwtii2ojrsp4bzhat4kanty/node_modules/@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs/dist/index.js:81:73)`
and
`Unhandled Promise Rejection    {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"TypeError: done is not a function","reason":{"errorType":"TypeError","errorMessage":"done is not a function","stack":["TypeError: done is not a function","    at /var/task/.next/server/chunks/166.js:43:12","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"]},"promise":{},"stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: TypeError: done is not a function","    at process.<anonymous> (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1188:17)","    at process.emit (node:events:525:35)","    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:149:20)","    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:283:27)","    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:32)"]}`
```

Comment: This looks like you are trying to mix the auth-helpers with an express auth library. You should just use the normal `supabase-js` in this circumstance as the auth-helpers are expecting NextJS request and response objects.